# Find next greater of every element using stack

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, stack

I am trying to find the next greater element of array. My logic is correct and the code is error-free, but I am unable to get output for every index. I am only getting it for index 0. After that, it is giving a segmentation fault. Here `a` is the input array, `n` is the size of array `a` and `next` is also an array used to store the immediate greater element of `a`.

```
   void gofindnextelement(int a[],int next[],int n)
   {
    stack<int>s;
    s.push(0);
    int i,curr;
    for( i=1;i<n;i++){
         curr=a[i];
         while(a[s.top()]<curr && s.empty()==0){
         next[s.top()]=curr;
         cout<<"index=" << s.top()<<"--->"<<next[s.top()]<<endl;
         s.pop();
         } 
         s.push(i);

   }    
   while(s.empty()==0)
     { 

    next[s.top()]=-1;
    cout<<"index=" << s.top()<<"--->"<<next[s.top()]<<endl;
    s.pop();
    }

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
cout<<next[i]<< " "<<endl;      

 }
```

Comment: however i made following changes now " while ( s.empty()==0&&a[s.top()]<curr )," then its working perfectly fine for every index. why is that so ? A && B iis same as B && A ryt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `s` is empty, then `s.top()` causes Undefined Behavior. So

```
s.empty()==0 && a[s.top()]<curr
```

is safe, but

```
a[s.top()]<curr && s.empty()==0
```

is not.